# Search info from SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I have creacted an SQL Database. I succsess fully insert data into database, but i want to search from database.

HTML

```
<body>
INSERT AREA
<br>

<form action="demo.php" method="post"/>

    <p>imei: <input type="text" name="input1"/> </p>

<select name="input2">
   <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" src="submit.png" alt="Submit Form" />

</form>
Search AREA 
<br>
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
 Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form> 
 </body>
```

demo.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '#');
define('DB_USER', '#');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1, input2) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_close();
?>
```

So all these work perfect , i insert data to SQL Database fine, but check the next php code for search, isn't return any info it just open with-out return value. *i have wipe the database info.
Database name : demo 
Host name :localhost

form.php

```
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'my username';
$db_password = 'my pass';
$db_database = 'demo';

// Database Connection String
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form action="demo.php" method="post"/>

   <p>imei: <input type="text" name="input1"/> </p>

 <select name="input2">
   <option value="1">111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="2">222222222222222222</option>
     <option value="3">33333333333333333</option>
        <option value="4">4444444444444444</option>
   </select>

  <br>
  <br>

<input type="image" src="submit.png" alt="Submit Form" />
</form>
<br>
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="term" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM demeo WHERE Description LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
echo 'Primary key: ' .$row['PRIMARYKEY'];  
echo '<br /> Code: ' .$row['input1'];  
echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['input2'];  

}  

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I **HIGHLY** recommend not using stringbashing to create SQL statements.  You open yourself up to all sorts of SQL injection issues later.  Instead, create a parametrized statement and pass in parameters.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) as you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: i am learnig php. so if you have suggestion from where i can start.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your first example, it seems that in the second one, your table and column names are incorrect.

Replace your current query:

```
SELECT * FROM demeo WHERE Description LIKE '%".$term."%'
```

With this query:

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE input2 LIKE '%".$term."%'}
```

Also consider the suggestions of the other users to avoid sql injections.

Comment: It's usually best to explain why you're making this recommendation even if it's just a quick note.

Comment: Now looks like a better answer.